# BuddyPress deactivates theme sidebar

Tags: wordpress, buddypress

I'm using the BuddyPress sidebar. The problem is that when I activate the plugin it deactivates my themes sidebar. So none of my BuddyPress pages have sidebars. All other plugins  like custom sidebars or conditional sidebars or sidebar logic failt to solve the problem. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

When you publish a regular WordPress Page (not a Post), and view it, does *that* page have the sidebar that you're expecting?